# CORS intranet (http) to internet (https) what are my options?

Tags: xdomainrequest

I have some JS that is on some intranet application that's running on HTTP (this server/service is out of my control, run by the customer). I operate the internet application and it must run on HTTPS for security purposes.

I'm attempting to use [XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) but I'm finding that the cookies aren't being sent. Is the problem that I'm going intranet to internet or that I'm going HTTP to HTTPS or some configuration problem?

I keep getting 401 when checking authentication of the user even after they have logged in.

I've verified the backend/internet service works as expected via a jsfiddle (i.e. Access-Control-Allow-Origin, etc. are all correct).

Thanks!

Comment: An XDomain instance cannot send cookies with its request. You'll need to communicate via iframes if you want to support old versions of IE.

Comment: @idbehold I believe that's how XDomain works, right; by creating an iFrame. Maybe I misunderstood how that library works.

Comment: Yes XDomain does use iframes. Have your tried the config `xdomain.cookies`?

Comment: Yep, tried it. It wasn't sending the right cookie. We'd also need to modify our endpoint to read this cookie differently via the header value.

I think our best bet is to utilize OAuth as we'll be able to send the access token and not have to rely on cookie authentication.

Answer (score 2):

There are some security related issues with XDomain that makes it strip any cookies according to no 5 in this [msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx). However there also exist a workaround using proxy with example project on [Github](https://github.com/jgauffin/CorsProxy). I think everything you need to make it work are described in those two pages.